# django-screamshot "Html Render IMG TAG Image is not coming while generating PDF"

Tags: django, pdf, casperjs

Using django-screamshot plug to generating PDF. 
Below is the URL of plugin

https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-screamshot

I am rending an HTML with Django-ScreamShot (CasperJs Option) to generate PDF.
Imaging are not coming after generating PDF. It is showing ? at the center.

Is it problem to rendering is fast so we need to wait ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative.

If we convert all the image to base64 and display them with image tag "**< img src=' data:image/png;base64, ...' / >**" image are coming in PDF also.
But if we use direct URL of image it don't show up on PDF and comes with ? at the center.

****Note I think when Casper Take a screenshot it don't wait for image to get load. So better convert all the images to base64 and display them in PDF also.**